# Why does gcloud crash while installing App Engine Java Component in Windows 10

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I recently installed Google Cloud SDK on Windows 10, using the installer and it was successful. But when I run the following command `gcloud components install app-engine-java`, gcloud crashes with error. (see console output below). Does anyone know why?

```
Your current Google Cloud CLI version is: 404.0.0
Installing components from version: 404.0.0

+-------------------------------------------------+
|       These components will be installed.       |
+----------------------------+---------+----------+
|            Name            | Version |   Size   |
+----------------------------+---------+----------+
| gcloud app Java Extensions |   2.0.8 | 73.2 MiB |
+----------------------------+---------+----------+

For the latest full release notes, please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

#============================================================#
#= Creating update staging area                             =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: gcloud app Java Extensions                   =#
#============================================================#
ERROR: gcloud crashed (FileNotFoundError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Wizy\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk.staging\\platform\\google_appengine\\google\\appengine\\tools\\java\\jetty94\\jetty-home\\demo-base\\webapps\\doc\\9.4.48.v20220622\\configuring\\deploying\\images\\Jetty_DeployManager_DefaultAppLifeCycleBindings.png'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: That path is 262 characters long (after replacing the doubled backslashes). Some filesystem APIs in Windows are limited to 255 characters, likely that is causing the problem here (but I don't know conclusively, so posting it as a comment, not an answer).

Comment: The path in the error is 264 characters long. By default, Windows has a limit of about 260 characters (MAX_PATH) unless **NTFS Long Paths** is enabled.

Comment: I navigated to Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration ->. Administrative Templates -> System -> Filesystem and enabled Long Paths, hope there is no adverse effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got the app-engine-java component to install successfully.

First, following the suggestion by @Mark_Rotteveel and @John_Hanley I enabled Long Path by;

> Navigating to Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration ->.
> Administrative Templates -> System -> Filesystem and enabled Long
> Paths.

Secondly, I uninstalled and reinstalled the Cloud SDK, then ran the command `gcloud component install  app-engine-java` and it installed successfully.